# How to run exec in binary nodejs App running as a Daemon in Linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, daemon, systemd

I have a nodejs App.When i start the App from CLI with nodejs app.js all works fine, but if the App runns as a daemon the exec command inside app don't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running your app as a daemon? You can check the [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) tool for that via npm, which will handle exec commands as supposed.